# Mirroring Log a Call From Classic UI to Lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforce-classic, global-actions, log-a-call

Someone recently brought a request to my attention, to help with transitioning from classic to lightning. They're wondering if we're able to mirror the formatting/layout/fields available when using the "Log a Call" button, that currently resides on the activities tab of an opportunity record page. In classic UI, when using the log a call button, the page layout seems to be broken into three big sections, one of which allows you to add a follow up task right from the same screen. In lightning, at least from my experience, you're having to click the "create follow up task" button once you've marked a task as complete, to make another one.

I believe I understand said buttons, the "Log a Call" one, is a global action, however I can't seem to find where I can edit *that* specific global action. In setup I can of course find ~30 other global action buttons and see their layouts, but I'm not seeing this one. Do I just need to make a new global action, call it log a call, and add the fields they're requesting? I have a feeling there isn't anyway to get the logging of a call and creating of a subsequent task all on the same single screen.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The layout for Log a Call is located, in Lightning Setup, under User Interface->Global Actions->Global Actions, named "Log a Call".

You can edit the layout for the action to add new fields you've added to the Task object, like `Custom_Follow_Up_Due_Date__c`, and similar, and then use a Process to create and insert a new follow-up task based on the user's population of those fields.

However, if you want a more developed experience liked the original Classic Log a Call screen, you'd need to build a completely new action, probably using a Lightning component or Visualforce. For example, you cannot create page sections in the layout of the standard Global Action.

Comment: (not sure if that tagging worked...) thank you for the insight! I was able to go in and make a new log a call global action and add some fields, however I don't think I'll get it _exactly_ the way this one person wants it, at least not without using process builder as you mentioned. I can certainly do that, its just way down on my list. I honestly don't really understand why they can't use the built in way of doing it, its just fine for everyone else! Thanks again.

Comment: @DevinPearman User expectation management is harder than programming :)